# The method of calculating the delay between pressing the button and the execution of line of code

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to evaluate in Java/JavaFX the delay between pressing the keyboard button and the execution of the line of code? Imagine situation, where I present a stimulus to the user and its task is to hit SPACE key when he or she perceive that stimulus. How can I get most accurately the delay between display the stimulus and hitting the keyboard key?

To this day I've used something like this:

```
long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
displayTheStimulus();

long end_time;
if (spacebarIsHitted()) {
    end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
} else {
    end_time = start_time;
}

long difference = end_time-start_time
```

How can I be sure, that values given by this method are valid and accurate? Is there a way to evaluate how accurate this method is?

Answer (score 1):

According to java [System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) documentation, you can use System.nanoTime() to measure how long some action takes, which uses higher resolution timer (subject to availability on the underlying platform). Based on the platform you might have a slight error rate.

Furthermore since you are using JavaFX for GUI, the following is copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384220/time-event-was-sent)

> According to JavaFX Architecture it uses the native event queue for
>   capturing and batching all the events. By capturing it is understood
>   that at that moment in time the event was generated (the user clicked
>   the button). Taking batching into account we have already lost the
>   information about the time the event was generated (unless JavaFX
>   internally keeps that information, you can inspect com.sun.javafx
>   packages for lower level details). Every 1/60th of a second there is a
>   scheduled pulse event. During the pulse event all other JavaFX events
>   like MouseEvent, etc. are fired via the normal JavaFX event
>   dispatching mechanism. It is at this point that your application will
>   receive a notification from JavaFX that an event has occurred. So in
>   an ideal world the difference between the time an event was posted and
>   the time it was handled should be < 0.0166(6) seconds.

In short, when the SPACE key is **actually** hit and when JavaFX tells you when the key was hit are different values, where difference **should be < 0.0166(6) seconds**. So you must take this into account. It's also worth noting that if for any reason JavaFX Application Thread gets delayed, the difference will also increase, hence greater error rate.